# javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported

Tags: java, audio-recording

I am getting this error 
Line unavailable: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.

when i am trying to capture multiple voices (One after another). Sometimes my code works fine and sometimes it gives the above mentioned error.
Note: i am coding from this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

Reason + Solution. Thanks